# Filter grouped dataframe by value in another dataframe with same group IDs in R

Tags: r, filtering, subset

I am hoping someone can help me with this problem I am having working with a large dataset in R. I have a dataframe consisting of thousands of tree IDs, year of measurement, and diameter in the given measurement year. I would like to filter this dataframe so that I retain only rows predating the death of the neighboring tree. I have a second dataframe that contains tree IDs and the year the neighboring tree died, to provide the year to filter by.

Small bit of original df (4 trees only):

```
   tree_id year diameter
1       T1 1978     48.2
2       T1 1990     48.6
3       T1 1995     49.0
4       T1 2002     49.6
5       T1 2008     50.3
6       T1 2012     50.4
7       T1 2017     50.6
8       T2 1978     76.3
9       T2 1984     76.8
10      T2 1990     77.3
11      T2 1995     78.7
12      T2 2002     79.5
13      T2 2008     80.6
14      T2 2012     81.1
15      T2 2017     81.6
16      T3 1978     15.7
17      T3 1984     16.5
18      T3 1990     17.7
19      T3 1995     18.3
20      T3 2002     19.3
21      T3 2008     20.0
22      T3 2012     20.0
23      T3 2017     20.2
24      T4 1978     50.5
25      T4 1984     51.2
26      T4 1990     51.9
27      T4 1995     52.5
28      T4 2002     53.2
29      T4 2008     54.8
30      T4 2012     53.7
31      T4 2017     54.0
```

And here is the dataframe I would like to filter the above by:

```
  tree_id neb_death
1      T1      2002
2      T2      2008
3      T3      1995
4      T4      2012
```

For example, I would like to only retain rows in the larger dataframe for tree_id = T1 with measurement years before 2002. I'd really appreciate any help either with base R or dplyr approaches.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the role of the second data.frame? In your example, doesn't this give you want you want: df_example <- df[df$tree_id == "T1" & year < 2002,]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data.table to join on matching `tree_id` and `year < neb_death`. If the first table is `df` and the second is `df2`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setDT(df2)

df[df2, on = .(tree_id, year < neb_death)]
#>     tree_id  year diameter
#>      <char> <int>    <num>
#>  1:      T1  2002     48.2
#>  2:      T1  2002     48.6
#>  3:      T1  2002     49.0
#>  4:      T2  2008     76.3
#>  5:      T2  2008     76.8
#>  6:      T2  2008     77.3
#>  7:      T2  2008     78.7
#>  8:      T2  2008     79.5
#>  9:      T3  1995     15.7
#> 10:      T3  1995     16.5
#> 11:      T3  1995     17.7
#> 12:      T4  2012     50.5
#> 13:      T4  2012     51.2
#> 14:      T4  2012     51.9
#> 15:      T4  2012     52.5
#> 16:      T4  2012     53.2
#> 17:      T4  2012     54.8
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Data used

```
df <- structure(list(tree_id = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", 
"T4", "T4", "T4"), year = c(1978L, 1990L, 1995L, 2002L, 2008L, 
2012L, 2017L, 1978L, 1984L, 1990L, 1995L, 2002L, 2008L, 2012L, 
2017L, 1978L, 1984L, 1990L, 1995L, 2002L, 2008L, 2012L, 2017L, 
1978L, 1984L, 1990L, 1995L, 2002L, 2008L, 2012L, 2017L), diameter = c(48.2, 
48.6, 49, 49.6, 50.3, 50.4, 50.6, 76.3, 76.8, 77.3, 78.7, 79.5, 
80.6, 81.1, 81.6, 15.7, 16.5, 17.7, 18.3, 19.3, 20, 20, 20.2, 
50.5, 51.2, 51.9, 52.5, 53.2, 54.8, 53.7, 54)), row.names = c(NA, 
-31L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(tree_id = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"), neb_death = c(2002L, 
2008L, 1995L, 2012L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks @IceCreamToucan! That's perfect! @TarJae, your solution also gets it done! I was having a real brain fart on this one. You both rock :)

Answer (score 1):

We could first `left_join` by `tree_id` and then `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df, df1, by="tree_id") %>% 
  filter(year < neb_death) %>% 
  select(-neb_death)
```

output:

```
   tree_id  year diameter
   <chr>   <int>    <dbl>
 1 T1       1978     48.2
 2 T1       1990     48.6
 3 T1       1995     49  
 4 T2       1978     76.3
 5 T2       1984     76.8
 6 T2       1990     77.3
 7 T2       1995     78.7
 8 T2       2002     79.5
 9 T3       1978     15.7
10 T3       1984     16.5
11 T3       1990     17.7
12 T4       1978     50.5
13 T4       1984     51.2
14 T4       1990     51.9
15 T4       1995     52.5
16 T4       2002     53.2
17 T4       2008     54.8
```

Comment: Ah. Clear. Many thanks @IceCream Toucan.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R we could loop row-wise over `df2`, identify unwanted observations in `df1` and remove them.

```
df1[-unlist(apply(df2, 1, \(x) which(df1$tree_id == x[1] & df1$year >= x[2]))), ]
#    tree_id year diameter
# 1       T1 1978     48.2
# 2       T1 1990     48.6
# 3       T1 1995     49.0
# 8       T2 1978     76.3
# 9       T2 1984     76.8
# 10      T2 1990     77.3
# 11      T2 1995     78.7
# 12      T2 2002     79.5
# 16      T3 1978     15.7
# 17      T3 1984     16.5
# 18      T3 1990     17.7
# 24      T4 1978     50.5
# 25      T4 1984     51.2
# 26      T4 1990     51.9
# 27      T4 1995     52.5
# 28      T4 2002     53.2
# 29      T4 2008     54.8
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(tree_id = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", 
"T4", "T4", "T4"), year = c(1978L, 1990L, 1995L, 2002L, 2008L, 
2012L, 2017L, 1978L, 1984L, 1990L, 1995L, 2002L, 2008L, 2012L, 
2017L, 1978L, 1984L, 1990L, 1995L, 2002L, 2008L, 2012L, 2017L, 
1978L, 1984L, 1990L, 1995L, 2002L, 2008L, 2012L, 2017L), diameter = c(48.2, 
48.6, 49, 49.6, 50.3, 50.4, 50.6, 76.3, 76.8, 77.3, 78.7, 79.5, 
80.6, 81.1, 81.6, 15.7, 16.5, 17.7, 18.3, 19.3, 20, 20, 20.2, 
50.5, 51.2, 51.9, 52.5, 53.2, 54.8, 53.7, 54)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"))

df2 <- structure(list(tree_id = c("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4"), neb_death = c(2002L, 
2008L, 1995L, 2012L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Hi @jay.sf Just wanted to give you a shout out! I ended up coming back and using your solution in my final script. Very nice, and I understand it better, so I was able to tweak it to solve another challenging filtering problem (challenging for me anyhow!). Thanks!!